# spring security access unprivileged resource leading to loop redirect

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, infinite-loop

### spring security remember-me login acces unprivilege resource causing infinite loop redirect

> There some roles in my project for accessing different resources.
> when user accessing unauthorized resource,it should be redirect to one error page such as 403 page, therefor i write my **access deny handler** to redirect this requests.
> when it run,i find my unauthorized request stuck in infinite loop login action using **remember-me** to login, but it works fine in common **username password** login.

there two type access deny exceptions via reading related resources, one is user is unauthorized, another is resource is unauthorized. the key filter is **ExceptionTranslationFilter**,it write as below:(some point snippets)(official code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.java))

```java
    if (authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication) || authenticationTrustResolver.isRememberMe(authentication)) {
                    logger.debug(
                            "Access is denied (user is " + (authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication) ? "anonymous" : "not fully authenticated") + "); redirecting to authentication entry point",
                            exception);
    
                    sendStartAuthentication(
                            request,
                            response,
                            chain,
                            new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
                                    "Full authentication is required to access this resource"));
                }
                else {
                    logger.debug(
                            "Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler",
                            exception);
    
                    accessDeniedHandler.handle(request, response,
                            (AccessDeniedException) exception);
                }
```

i have found it dealt with unauthorized user when using remember-me to login, it will be auto login by cookies without question,
but the AuthenticationEntryPoint will redirect login page again....
and on the other hand, it is useless to rewrite AuthenticationEntryPoint which can decide request to redirecting which page since the SecurityContext has been cleared at sendStartAuthentication method,see as follow snippets:

```java
    protected void sendStartAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
                AuthenticationException reason) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // SEC-112: Clear the SecurityContextHolder's Authentication, as the
            // existing Authentication is no longer considered valid
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
            requestCache.saveRequest(request, response);
            logger.debug("Calling Authentication entry point.");
            authenticationEntryPoint.commence(request, response, reason);
        }
```

i am using spring security 4.2.2 release and i found remember-me login is ok when accessing deny at previous version before 4.1.x,([here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.1.x/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.java) it is) and you can find this 'issue' at this link: `github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2427`.

At last,i dont wanna use previous version, how can fix this problem about using remember-me login access the unauthorized resource?
**can anyone help me out?**